# Checking if model was modified using repositories

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I update model using repository like this:

```
public function update($id, UpdateCompanyRequest $request)
{
    $attributes = $request->all();

    $oldCompany = $this->company->find($id);
    $newCompany = $this->company->update($id, $attributes);

    // Only if it was really updated
    event(new CompanyUpdated($oldCompany, $newCompany));

    return redirect()->route('companies.show', $id);
}
```

How can I compare if company was updated, including its relationships? For example, a company has an address and if I changed the address the event should be fired. But if nothing has been changed then I do not need to fire this event.

The only way I thought about manually checking each field/relationship which is ugly.

`isDirty()` works only before saving the model.